# Compilation error when using Parent::operator<=> in two derived classes only on gcc 12 but not in clang++14

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, spaceship-operator

Consider the following code `main.cpp`:

```
#include<compare>
struct Parent {
    int val;
    auto operator<=>(const Parent&) const = default;
};

struct Child1: public Parent {
    using Parent::operator<=>;
};

struct Child2: public Parent {
    using Parent::operator<=>;
};
int main()
{
}
```

It compiles for `clang++-14 -std=c++20 main.cpp` but not for `g++-12 -std=c++20 main.cpp`:

```
main.cpp:4:10: error: comparison operator ‘bool Parent::operator==(const Parent&) const’ defaulted after its first declaration
    4 |     auto operator<=>(const Parent&) const = default;
      |          ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:10: note: ‘bool Parent::operator==(const Parent&) const’ previously declared here
```

**Why?**

Comment: Why are you trying `using` instead of defaulting `operator<=>` like you did in the base class?

Comment: @user17732522 In this case this is equivalent but when there are additional members in the child classes, they would be also compared using the defaulted `operator<=>` but not using `using`.

Comment: @user17732522 In my use case however, your solution fits well because I don't have additional member variables introduced in the child classes, thank you.

Comment: If you don't want members in the child to be compared, then you don't need to add anything. The `operator<=>` and the implicit `operator==` from the base class are already found when comparing the child classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in GCC which you could file here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc

Here is a simple workaround:

```
struct Parent {
    int val;
    auto operator<=>(const Parent& h2) const;
};

struct Child1: public Parent {
    using Parent::operator<=>;
};

struct Child2: public Parent {
    using Parent::operator<=>;
};

inline auto Parent::operator<=>(const Parent& h2) const = default;
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same semantics. The classes can't be compared with `==` and `!=` if `operator<=>` is not defaulted on its first declaration (because only then `operator==` will be implicitly defined).

Comment: @user17732522 Great point, an `operator==` will also need to be declared if needed.